# Recreating history from snapshoted data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have a case where i need to compare snapshoted data(dbo.src) with destination table(dbo.dest) and find out which of the countries are new and which ones are not valid anymore.

**DATA:**

```
create table dbo.src
(
 MessageID int not null
,ProductID int not null
,Country varchar(2) null
,ChangeDate date not null
)

insert into dbo.src
(MessageID,ProductID, Country, ChangeDate)
values
 (1,1,'AT','2021-10-05')
,(2,1,'AT','2021-10-10')
,(2,1,'CH','2021-10-10')
,(3,1,'CH','2021-10-20')



create table dbo.dest
(
 ProductID int not null
,Country varchar(2) null
,ChangeDate date not null
,Active varchar(1) not null
)

insert into dbo.dest
(ProductID, Country, ChangeDate,Active)
values
 (1,'DE','2021-10-02','Y')
```

In dbo.dest table I already have one record with country DE and i have to compare it with the records in dbo.src in an exact way in which data arrived in source table(This can be tracked via column MessageID). Multiple changes arrived during some time period for the same product but different country setup.

**The desired output would look like this:**
[image: Desired outcome]

Here is how to interpret desired results:

1. In the 1st run we compared row from dbo.src with messageId=1 with current record in table dbo.dest. There is no more “DE” so we insert new record in dbo.dest with flag Active=N and put the date 2021-10-05 which would be some form of date when it became active. We also insert new record AT which would mean that new country arrived and became active.
2. In the 2nd run, we would compare rows from dbo.src with MessageID=2 and the last active record with latest ChangeDate and do the same comparison like in previous step. The result would be that we insert only CH with date 2021-10-10 and do nothing for AT record since its still coming from dbo.src table.
3. In the 3rd run we do the same comparisons like in previous 2 steps. The result would be inserting only new record for AT with active=N and date 2021-10-20 since this record no longer exists in dbo.src table where MessageID=3

How can this be done without cursors or loops?

Comment: Why is `Country = AT` with `ChangeDate = 2021-10-20` not active?...Is it because the older one on `2021-10-05` was already marked active? Was the older one on `2021-10-05` only marked active because `DE` is no longer in the `src` table? What if there were no rows in the `dest` table, would `Country = AT` with `ChangeDate = 2021-10-05` still be marked active? Why is `Country = CH` with `ChangeDate = 2021-10-20` not in your final results?

Comment: @J.D., as I understand it, every snapshot of data (MessageID) contains the list of currently active countries for each ProductID, so when a country is not listed in the following MessageID it means it is no longer active and vice versa.

Comment: This is a "Gaps And Islands" problem. Detailed explanation, with examples, is [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/gaps-islands-sql-server-data/)

Comment: @Alex I think it's a little more complex than that. E.g. why is `Country = AT` with `ChangeDate = 2021-10-20` not active? (It is in the following `MessageId = 2`). Also why is `Country = CH` with `ChangeDate = 2021-10-20` completely omitted from the final results? (It is neither listed as active or not active.)

Comment: My understanding: he has snapshots of Product/Country data denoted by MessageID and ChangeDate. He wants to generate records showing when a specific country was assigned to product (activated) and then stopped being assigned (diactivated) to a product i.e. gaps and islands.  "why is Country = AT with ChangeDate = 2021-10-20 not active?" - it is activated in MessageID = 1 ('2021-10-05'), still present in MessageID  = 2 (no change) and not in MessageID = 3 i.e. it was "deactivated" in snapshot 3.

Comment: @Alex you are right with your undertanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my attempt.

See comments in code for details:

```
;WITH CombinedList AS(
    -- Select ALL currentry Active records
    SELECT 0 AS MessageID, ProductID, Country, ChangeDate, Active FROM dest
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MessageID, ProductID, Country, ChangeDate, 'Y' AS Active FROM src ),
GroupedList AS(
    SELECT ProductID, Country, MessageID, ChangeDate,
        -- Calculates contiguous data group numbers
        MessageID - ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ProductID, Country ORDER BY MessageID ) AS rn
    FROM CombinedList
),
Islands AS(
    SELECT ProductID, Country, ActiveStart = MIN( MessageID ), ActiveEnd = MAX( MessageID )
    FROM GroupedList AS a
    GROUP BY ProductID, Country, rn
),
StartStopRecords AS(
    -- Create Start Records
    SELECT I.ProductID, I.Country, AStart.ChangeDate, 'Y' AS Active
    FROM Islands AS I
        INNER JOIN GroupedList AS AStart ON I.ProductID = AStart.ProductID AND I.Country = AStart.Country AND I.ActiveStart = AStart.MessageID
    UNION ALL
    -- Create Stop Records
    SELECT I.ProductID, I.Country, AEnd.ChangeDate, 'N' AS Active
    FROM Islands AS I
        -- Create a Stop record only if subsequent Message has arrived
        CROSS APPLY( SELECT TOP 1 ChangeDate FROM GroupedList WHERE I.ActiveEnd < MessageID ORDER BY MessageID ) AS AEnd
)
-- Final Result
SELECT *
FROM StartStopRecords
ORDER BY ProductID, ChangeDate, Country
```

Some of the code was adopted from [Gaps and Islands performance comparison article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/gaps-islands-sql-server-data/) by Dwain Camps.